# A question about softwares coming from a compleye newbie

Tags: windows

I am almost sure that this will be flagged as a duplicate but I really need some organized answers.

In Windows apps come in .exe type. Simple.

In Ubuntu, I've seen 3 types.

1. Apps I download from USC.
2. Apps I get through the Terminal.
3. "Portable" apps I download through my browser.

What is the difference ?

Is there a way to have all my apps in one manager as in Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

> In Windows apps come in .exe type. Simple.

Let me draw a small analogy to Windows. `.exe` files are binary files and there's `.bat` scripts under windows. Same thing exists in *nix systems, however,Linux/Unix does not necessarily rely on extensions to define executable files. You might occasionally find `.run` scripts from proprietary software wendors, but under the hood they are really text files. Mostly, extensions are the choice of the developer. For instance, I add `.sh` extension for shell scripts , but they are not a requirement - just my own preference. Because I compile C programs with `gcc` compiler, by default the binary file comes out with `.out` extensions, but if I wanted to I could save it without one.

For instance , if you run  `ls -l $(which gnome-terminal)` command in terminal (where `which` command finds gnome-terminal and then `ls` lists its properties ), you will see this:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3511 Apr  8 10:34 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal*`

No extension, but the file itself is executable. More so , if we try to determine what type of file is that, we find something interesting:

```
$ file $(which gnome-terminal)
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

It's a script ! It's a text file that you can view !

But there's another file , that is being called in the script above `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real` . What does `file` tell us ?

```
$ file /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=3ad9f22b9c39e314bc13cdd74f5917711986ca4d, stripped
```

So the python script actually sets up environment for the actual executable.

*Notice*  the `-rwxr-xr-x` part in the output of `ls $(which gnome-terminal). See the rwx ? That's read-write-execute permissions for owner, read-execute for ower's group and other users (read left to right).  If we remove those x permissions for the group and other users , the app is still a working app, but nobody but its owner (root user) will be able to execute it. It may be analogous to Local Group Policy in Windows

As for software from USC and terminal (I'm assuming you use `apt-get` ), they are pretty much the same, mostly binary files. Portable Apps, such as plugins and addons for firefox, are most likely in javascript. But I am not knowledgeable enough of those, so I won't tell for sure.

> Is there a way to have all my apps in one manager as in Windows ?

Technically, you already have one manager for programs under Linux - they're called package managers, `e.g. apt-get, yum` . With windows you install exe files you download from the web, right ? With Linux you can do that, but more commonly it is done through `ppa` repositories. `apt-get` has a list of sources out there on the web. When you install something, like `sudo apt-get install someprog` , we check those sources, and if the program exists, `apt-get` downloads it, as well as required libraries and programs, and gives them to `dpkg`, which install them . Ubuntu Software Centre does same thing, in fact , it is using `apt-get` behind the scenes.   But `apt-get` is Ubuntu thing. If you look at Red Hat or Fedora, they use `yum`. Same idea - use repositories to search and install software.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, the executability (what you would probably call "appiness") of any particular file is NOT encoded in the filename (`.exe`), but rather in the file permission bits. Please learn more about Linux.

If you restrict yourself to applications installed using the Debian/Ubuntu package management system (e.g. `dpkg`,`apt-get`,`synaptic` are tools using it), then the same set of tools can list what you have installed using the tools. If, however, you download something from `evil.example.org` and install it (or, following included instructions, do `sudo` anything) you are on your own. You will have to keep track of those things yourself.

There are tools that will let you monitor things like the addition of executables to directories in your `$PATH`, like Bastille-Linux [read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BastilleLinux)
but also read [this](http://linux-audit.com/alternatives-to-bastille-linux-system-hardening-with-lynis/) or Lynis [here](https://cisofy.com/), but they seem out-of-scope for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu (and basically every other flavor of Linux), most software is installed through software repositories, which is just some unified place from which you can download software. Ubuntu pulls software packages from a number of repositories by default, but you can also add or remove repositories manually from the terminal or the System Settings program. Anytime you run `sudo apt-get install <package name>`, you are downloading and installing from a repository. Same story if you download from the Ubuntu Software Center, which I think of as a graphical representation of the Ubuntu's repositories, although I'm sure it's different in some regards. Both of those come with a number of benefits, particularly safer software that is reviewed before publishing, and updates delivered directly with all your other software updates. In other words, using the USC or `apt-get` in the terminal really isn't that different.

But not all software is available from a software repository. Or sometimes it's just easier to download a file and install it that way. I think of a .deb as the closest thing to an .exe installer in Ubuntu. But it's a little bit different. A .deb will open the USC for installation, and, at least in some cases, reference a software repository so it will also be updated with all your other software. Google Chrome is a perfect example of this.

Unfortunately, not all software is available with a Debian-friendly .deb installer or in a software repository. These are frequently available as a .tar.gz, which is just a compressed folder format. These require the user to compile the source code manually from the terminal, using `make` if I recall correctly. I haven't installed many, if any, programs using this method, so I don't know a whole lot about it, but I wouldn't expect them to update through the software updater.

As far as organizing your apps, all your programs should show up in the Unity Dash (activated by the "Super" key, which probably has a Windows logo on it). As such, any program can be pinned to the Launcher, or the dock. However, as far as a comprehensive list with a nice, friendly "uninstall" button, I don't know of any way of unifying the software you've installed from all these different sources under one roof. The USC has an "Installed" tab from which you can view all your installed software, sorted by repositories listed in the drop-down menu. But any software you've compiled yourself will most likely be absent from that list.

I hope this explanation was helpful. I also hope I'm not filling your head with misinformation, so all you Linux gurus out there, please correct me if I am mistaken when it comes to any of this stuff.